# How to extract a string between a space and a dot (.)?

Tags: r, string

I have this string:

"White, Mr. George Voultsios"

And I would like to extract the part between the space and the dot:

"Mr"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x<-"White, Mr. George Voultsios"
sub(".* ","",sub("\\..*","",x))
[1] "Mr"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions with a lookbehind for the space and a lookahead for the dot:

```
## The data:    
x <- c("White, Mr. George Voultsios", "LastName, Mrs. Firstname")
```

Using the base package:

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("(?<= ).*(?=\\.)", x, perl = TRUE))
# [1] "Mr"  "Mrs"
```

Using the package `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
stringr::str_extract(x, "(?<= ).*(?=\\.)")
# [1] "Mr"  "Mrs"
```

What the pattern `(?<= ).*(?=\\.)` does is:

- look for a position following a space (`(?<= )`)
- then capture any number of characters (`.*`)
- until you get to a position that is followed by a dot (`(?=\\.)`)